# Convert date to varchar then compare

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table info with a datetime column `begindate`.

I've tried the following 2 SQL statements:

```
select * 
from info 
where begindate > '06/30/2018'

select * 
from info 
where convert(varchar, begindate, 101) > '06/30/2018'
```

The first query result is correct, but the second query result wrongly included those begindate later than '06/30/2017'.

Can anyone tell me what the reason for this is? Are there any online resources about it? Thanks

Comment: Think which one is greater when '01/01/2018' and '12/31/2017' are compared as string.

Comment: If you are comparing date with date then why do you want to convert it to varchar?

Comment: when you cast the date to a string, you're now doing a string comparison which might change results -- and if you want dates *before* 30/06 you should use `<` rather than `>`

Answer (score 5):

The reason is that string comparison and `DateTime` comparison works differently.

And in any case, you do not want to convert the value of the column since it will prevent SQL Server to use any indexes that might contain this column.

The best thing to do is to compare the data in your column to a `DateTime` data type, and not to a string.

If you are using a literal string for a `DateTime` value, the best option is to use ISO 8601 format - `yyyy-mm-ddTHH:mm:ss.mmm` (`2018-06-30T00:00:00`) or it's less human readable alternative `yyyymmdd` (`20180630`) if you only care about the date itself - This will enable SQL Server to correctly convert the string value to a `DateTime`, as it's unambiguous and not culture-dependent.

BTW, [you should stop using `DateTime` and switch to `DateTime2` instead.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cdnsoldevs/2011/06/22/why-you-should-never-use-datetime-again/)

Comment: `If you are using a literal string for a DateTime value, the best option is to ` ... stop doing that. ;) +1

Comment: @TZHX sometimes you don't have a choice :-)

Answer (score 0):

As I checked:

**First Query:** Which will return the rows for you without the proper comparison because you are comparing `datetime` with the string `Date`

```
SELECT * 
FROM info 
WHERE begindate>'06/30/2018'
```

**Second Query:** Which is working fine (Refer the script)

```
SELECT * 
FROM info 
WHERE convert(varchar,begindate,101)>'06/30/2018'
```

Here is the script:

```
CREATE TABLE INFO
(
beginDate datetime NULL
)

INSERT INTO INFO VALUES ('2018-07-30 12:28:06.167')
INSERT INTO INFO VALUES ('2018-07-03 12:28:06.167')


SELECT * FROM info where begindate>'06/30/2018'

SELECT * FROM info where convert(varchar,begindate,101)>'06/30/2018'
```

Comment: when included in a convert statement, length in varchar is implicitly 20